# Nextjs 13: Can't resolve 'src/app/dashboard/layout.tsx' (deleted optional layout)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend

So I decided to create a new Nextjs 13.4.5 project with an app directory.

I created a new dashboard directory inside my app directory and then created page and layout component in the dashboard directory. It worked fine, there was two layout component: one was the root layout in the app directory, and the other one is the layout.tsx I created in the dashboard directory

Eventually I decided to delete the layout.tsx in the dashboard directory because I wanted to use only root layout, but an error occurred:

```
./
Module not found: Can't resolve '/myproject/src/app/dashboard/layout.tsx'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

I have searched in my project for any import statements or dynamic imports that reference the deleted dashboard/layout.tsx, but there is no reference

here is my tsconfig file:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
  "allowJs": false,
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "strict": true,
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "noEmit": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "module": "esnext",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "isolatedModules": true,
  "jsx": "preserve",
  "incremental": true,
  "plugins": [
  {
    "name": "next"
  }
],
"paths": {
  "@/*": ["./src/*"]
}
},
"include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
"exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

The whole problem is that when you create a new directory for a new page if you don't create layout.tsx inside that directory everything works fine.

but if you create a layout component inside that route directory and then delete it, Nextjs won't be able to render that route without its layout component and this is kinda weird.

Is there any way to solve this? because I don't wanna create an useless layout component for my route

Comment: tough to say without your code but sometimes their cache gets weird. there should be a `.next` folder in your project that's auto-generated. sometimes deleting that can help with these sorts of issues

Answer (score 17):

I had the exact same issue and deleting the .next folder worked for me! Thanks @imjared for that answer!

Comment: hit the same issue , delete .next worked for me . thanks !

Comment: But then what after deleting it?

Comment: It will regenerate in next build

Answer (score 4):

Next.JS saves cache on .cache folder on .next folder. When you delete the layout.tsx, the .next thinks that the layout.tsx is still present on the app directory.

**Deleting the .next folder will solve the issue.**

To take effect immediately, restart your application.

[image: .next folder]

Answer (score 0):

This issue is very annoying because it persists when you push to production...

Comment: I have pushed my project on vercel and I get a build error :

`Module not found: Can't resolve '/vercel/path0/app/loading.tsx'`